# Extjs 4 - How can I get the complete url with params from a currently loaded grid's store?

Tags: url, parameters, get, grid, extjs4

I have a grid loaded, I want to get the current stores URL which loaded the json data to it , and pass an extra param to it, and load this URL as a pdf, or xls. But how can I get the url?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the proxy and ExtraParams:

```
var url = grid.getStore().getProxy().url;
var params = grid.getStore().getProxy().extraParams;
```

Then, build the url:

```
var newUrl = url + '?' + Ext.Object.toQueryString (params);
```

And the newUrl will be something like this:

```
your_url_data.json?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

I don't think that exists a proxy method that do this but you can extend an existing proxy, as follows:

```
Ext.define ('MyProxy', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax' ,
    buildInternalUrl: function () {
        return this.url + '?' + Ext.Object.toQueryString (this.extraParams);
    }       
});
```

And then:

```
var newUrl = grid.getStore().getProxy().buildInternalUrl ();
```

Result is the same ;)

Here's you can find the doc of proxies: **[Ajax Proxy](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax)**

Comment: I do not want to set the extraParams. I do not want to change anything. This is a configured and loaded grid with existing extraParams. So I want to get, the url, and the extra params.
I can get the extra params, and the url separated, and put it together with javascript, but I wonder why isn't an extjs method exist to create this.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand your question. So let me understand better: you want to build an url made from the proxy url and extraParams, right?

Answer (score 1):

you can get the stores url by  `yourGrid.getStore().getProxy().url`

Comment: This just get the url, without the extraParams.

Comment: well you asked for the url. I assumed you read the extjs api for proxy. yourGrid.getStore().getProxy().extraParams holds the object where to add the extra params you need